# Are questions about using IDEs more suitable for Super User or Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I asked this question on Stack Overflow:

[Eclipse gives "sh: line 3: `;/root/Documents/mp3Eclipse/Test_MP3/Test_MP3;exit'" when I try to run mpg123 there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40618636/cannot-play-audio-file-through-mpg123-using-eclipse-rhel-release-6-6)

Doesn't Stack Overflow also answer questions about "programming tools"? Isn't Eclipse a programming tool? I normally have questions about setting up projects on IDEs such as Qt and Eclipse. Is there any Stack Exchange website that will more willingly answer such questions?

Is Super User a more appropriate site for questions about IDEs?

Comment: @rene I wanted to ask how I could ALSO run the code from Eclipse.

Comment: You get down votes on your question on SO because it is unclear what you;'re after and users make the same mistake I made, assuming you don't know how to run mpg13.

Comment: You ought to keep to form in that Stack Overflow post: Ask an actual (focused) question

Comment: I now know what is wrong with my question. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Are questions about setting up projects on IDEs more suitable for Super User or Stack Overflow?

Comment: @a_sid questions about applications are on topic on Superuser.  But questions still have to be specific and detailed, provide necessary research information, required to answer said question

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping me. I noticed that I am continuing to get downvotes for this question. Are the downvotes for THIS question or my SO question?

Comment: If the downvotes are for this question, please let me know what is currently wrong with my question. It is clear to me that my SO question is flawed but I don't know what is wrong with this question.

Comment: @a_sid I upvoted you because you're cooperative and seem to be asking in good faith. I think the remaining downvotes are because your SO question is unclosed, no downvotes, etc, so it's not clear why you're asking about whether you should have posted it on SU instead of SO. If the fundamental motivation is "because I haven't gotten an answer and I want an answer", then the Meta machine will interpret that as whining or "spam" ("advertising" your Q on Meta rather than using a bounty). You'll p. get more upvotes if you frame he Q *purely* about where to ask IDE Qs & remove the link to your SO Q.

Comment: @DanBron Thank you. That was helpful.

Comment: Ugh, the duplicate questions are ancient and seem to imply that all questions about the use of an IDE belong on SO. That makes no sense to me. Personally, I think SuperUser is often *much* more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doesn't Stack Overflow also answer questions about "programming tools"?

Yes. It does. But that doesn't mean that every question will get an answer. Sometimes there isn't an answer or no one has the expertise or interest in answering. Some questions are just not well-written or unanswerable because they are unclear. Often those posts will get downvotes or will get closed.

> Is there any Stack Exchange website that will more willingly answer such questions?

No. Stack Overflow is the appropriate place. Try to improve your question, if it is super clear: add a bounty to attract views.

> Is Super User a more appropriate site for questions about IDEs?

No. It will get closed for sure.

> It is clear to me that my SO question is flawed.

Maybe you should try to see it from the perspective of the user visiting your question. What would you need to answer the question? Try to improve your question rather than blaming someone else.

Comment: My motive was to have answers to the questions you already answered. Thank you.